# 2 windows, 1 button needs to pull new image from LoremPixel

Tags: javascript, button, partial-page-refresh

I am building a site called DrawSome, which needs to display 2 random images for people to fuse through drawing.

[image]

On the picture you see the basic display of the site. I want the user to be able to load 2 new images in the boxes, when clicking on the button. It is important only the image-boxes refreshes, and not the whole site.  My idea was to pull the images from lorempixel.com, so I don't have to create a database.

**Which script do I use to create the refresh in the window only? jQuery?**

**How do I go around making this simple function?**

So far I only have this, which do not solve my problem. It only pulls the images locally, and do not refresh the image windows.

```
var changeImg = function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.random_img').css({'content': 'url(images/img' + Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-1+1)+1) +'.jpg)'});            
  });  
};

$(document).ready(changeImg);
```

Hope you consider this rookie question - we all have to start somewhere.

All the best,
Esben

Comment: Have you done your research? What have you tried? Some code examples?
I am sorry, but SO is about helping the user fixing his code problems, not writing the code for the user or giving opinion based answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Alright, then I have misunderstood the purpose.

I should mention I do not want anyone to write the code for me (then I will fail my exams and not learn anything). But I'm simply looking for a pointer in the right direction, since I do not know which library to look for the solution. 

I have been researching. The topics I am able to find is all about refreshing the whole page.

Comment: I have added some code I got from my teacher in the first post, but it only pulls local images, and do not refresh the window which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, the code you have will set tha background url of the `.random_img` element to a random local image (img1/2/3.jpg). You should probably change the url attribute to an image supplied by lorempixel, then try to add some kind of randomization logic to it.

Comment: Lorempixel does provide a random image by default, each time the page is reloaded. Try refreshing this page, my clear up what I'm talking about: http://lorempixel.com/400/200/
My challenge is to only refresh the window where the images is contained, when the button is pressed.

Comment: Yes, but to get random images for multiple containers with a single button press you'll need to load different urls for each of the containers. Like, adding a query string `http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?randomstringhere` at the end of the url you're loading to achieve this.
I suggest looking into jQueries `each()` method and javascripts Math functions like `rand()`, `ceil()`, `floor()`. `$.each()` would be used to call the method on each of the containers. Also, your code has an error - I think what you're looking for is setting the css `background` property to the url, not content.

Comment: Thank you Pankucins, I will research on those topics.

Comment: I assembled a small example for you to play around with - http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/x79y77vf/

Comment: Thanks. It seems to make sense on the face of it. Will have to fragment each line to make sure I get it.
You mentioned that I should put some sort of random string at the end of the lorempixel url. How do I go about doing this? In my head, it does not make sense to change an url - wouldn't that lead me into a non existing part of the lorempixel site?